# Convert javascript value to upper case

Tags: javascript

I with to display this id value in upper case, how can I implement it with toUpperCase() in javascript?

```
<span id="rptTitle"></span>

<script>
    function rptTitle() {   document.getElementById("rptTitle").innerHTML=document.getElementById("sel1").value
}
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `toUpperCase`, try calling `toUpperCase` on a string to convert it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance although `.toLocaleUpperCase()` is probably better. [At the very least for Turkey](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<span id="rptTitle"></span>

<script>
function rptTitle() {  
    document.getElementById("rptTitle").innerHTML=document.getElementById("sel1").value.toUpperCase();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

js string has `toUpperCase()` case method
also you can do it via css `text-transform: uppercase`

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function rptTitle() {
    var str = "Hello World!";
    var res = str.toUpperCase();
    document.getElementById("rptTitle").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

this function will give you uppercase but make sure take values from div or p tag according to your need here i am using direct string "hello world".

for more information see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toUpperCase.asp)